# High confidence score on opencv EAST detection for cut-off text

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using this c++ sample source codes ([text_detection.cpp](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/dnn/text_detection.cpp)) of opencv EAST detection
for this cut-off text

[image]

and here is the result. 
I also draw the accuracy at below each detected text box.

[image]

All the detected text boxes have high confidence score, How to adjust the program so it will return lower confidence or no detection result for the image above?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the image, I'd call it a true positive. There is definitely text in the boxes drawn. Well, digits, but that's not the sort of difference you get from EAST.

You might be confusing EAST with an OCR algorithm; it isn't.

Comment: ok when i wrote false positive maybe too exaggerated, i will remove the words "false positive". But if you read the description, i was hoping the EAST returning low accuracy. As show on picture above the accuracy is very high (above 99%). btw i know the different with OCR, so the question is about finding the text box and give confident score. I expect because the character is not perfect (cut-off), the confident score should be low.

Comment: That's what I am saying. EAST is right. With 99% certainty, there **is** text in these boxes. Your assumptions are flawed, not just the two words "false positive".

Comment: so you meant, regardless the text is in corrupted or perfect shape. The EAST will return the same confidence score?

Comment: @Putra: It might not even _be_ text. Geometric patterns can be mis-detected. After all, something cross-shaped looks like an X after all. That might even fool a subsequent OCR stage. Look, AI works reasonably well today in specific cases, but we are miles away from strong AI.

Comment: in that case, the confidence score should be low isn't it. btw there are other characters on that picture that completely EAST can not detect. well, i am still trying to understand how to use this EAST feature including how to use the score confidence.

Comment: @Putra: If I had to guess, it would be because of the inconsistent line width there. It seems that EAST learned to recognize the fact that most fonts have a fairly constant stroke width. Some of the unrecognized characters seem to be cut midway through a horizontal stroke.